# Getting error on viewing Scene Service using ArcGIS Javascript API - Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'code' in false

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I am using ArcGIS Javascript API 4.11. I'm getting these errors while viewing Scene Service from my portal and providing its Id.

Here is the screenshot of the error that I receive. [Screenshot 01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcavp.png)

This is the code that I use.

```
require([
  "esri/Map",
  "esri/views/SceneView",
  "esri/layers/SceneLayer",
  "esri/identity/OAuthInfo",
  "esri/identity/IdentityManager",
  "esri/layers/ImageryLayer",
  "esri/views/layers/ImageryLayerView"
], function(
  Map, SceneView, SceneLayer, OAuthInfo, esriId, ImageryLayer, ImageryLayerView
) {
  debugger;
  var info = new OAuthInfo({
    appId: "AnFbtGbH4t9A2XTi",
    // appId: "q244Lb8gDRgWQ8hM",
    // Uncomment the next line and update if using your own portal
    // portalUrl: "https://<host>:<port>/arcgis"
    // Uncomment the next line to prevent the user's signed in state from being shared with other apps on the same domain with the same authNamespace value.
    // authNamespace: "portal_oauth_inline",
    popup: false
  });

  esriId.registerOAuthInfos([info]);

  esriId
  .checkSignInStatus(info.portalUrl + "/sharing")
  .then(function() {
    //displayItems();
  }).catch(function() {
    // Anonymous view
    esriId.getCredential(info.portalUrl + "/sharing");
  });

  var map = new Map({
    basemap: "dark-gray",
    ground: "world-elevation"
  });

  var view = new SceneView({
    container: "viewDiv",
    map: map,
  });

  var sceneLayer = new SceneLayer({
    portalItem: {
      id: "e7bf9f676ed64937bff9f44c84fdae2b"
    },
    popupEnabled: false
  });

  map.add(sceneLayer);
});
```

The map is getting loaded but the scene layer is not getting loaded. Please help.

Similar code I tried in codepen with the same Id also gives me the same error - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rEqgJB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [portal item](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=e7bf9f676ed64937bff9f44c84fdae2b) you are trying to load is in fact a [BuildingSceneLayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-BuildingSceneLayer.html). The above code tries to load it as a regular [SceneLayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-SceneLayer.html).

That's why the API reports an error `SceneLayer does not support this layer type` (2nd error in your screenshot).

Simply replace `SceneLayer` with `BuildingSceneLayer` and everything works:

```
require([
  "esri/Map",
  "esri/views/SceneView",
  "esri/layers/BuildingSceneLayer"
], function(Map, SceneView, BuildingSceneLayer) {

...

  // Create BuildingSceneLayer and add to the map
  var sceneLayer = new BuildingSceneLayer({
    portalItem: {
      id: "e7bf9f676ed64937bff9f44c84fdae2b"
    },
    popupEnabled: false
  });
  map.add(sceneLayer);

...

});
```

Here is a fixed Codepen that shows the building after loading the layer.
https://codepen.io/arnofiva/pen/c410babb5384945a12b1d8206ebe27ce?editors=1010

---

An alternative way to achieve the same is asking the API to [load an arbitrary layer from a portal item](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/layers-portal/index.html), in which case it automatically detects the layer type:

```
Layer.fromPortalItem({
  portalItem: {
    id: "e7bf9f676ed64937bff9f44c84fdae2b"
  }
}).then(function(layer) {
  // Adds layer to the map
  map.add(layer);
});
```

---

You might want to checkout these samples showing BuildingSceneLayer-specific capabilities:

- [BuildingSceneLayer with Slice widget](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/building-scene-layer-slice/index.html)
- [Filter BuildingScenelayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/building-scene-layer-filter/index.html)

Comment: I viewed this scene after saving the Scene Layer as a scene. But the Building is not getting loaded even though I have signed in to the same account. Building only gets viewed if the Scene Layer is shared as public. Will that issue be fixed if I'm using BuildingSceneLayer?

Also is there a C# API for ArcGIS which I can use to upload Revit files with GeoCoordinates to my portal as Scene Layer(.slpk)?

Comment: Can you share the link to the web scene you saved?

Comment: 195a0f34c4a4427aa8464abee8a48634 - this is the id.

Comment: I have got the same issue viewing non shared files using BuildingSceneLayer. When I view using your code, a login popup appears, how do i enable that?

Comment: I see, yes that's expected. If the portal item is not public, the API will show a dialog to login. That is the case for any layer type.

Comment: For me popup does not appear.

Comment: As this is off topic, feel free to post a new SO question providing all the details or ask the community on https://community.esri.com/